# Full outer join on 3 tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, full-outer-join

I'm trying to get a full result set of all combinations from 3 tables, but its not working because I can't figure out how to tell SQL-Server 2008 what I want.

I have simplified it down to the following similar problem... I have 3 tables:

```
table `date_ranges`:
  --------------------------------------------------------
| start_day                  | end_day                     |
| -------------------------------------------------------- |
| November, 01 2015 14:37:00 | November, 02 2015 00:00:00  |
| November, 02 2015 00:00:00 | November, 03 2015 00:00:00  |
| November, 03 2015 00:00:00 | November, 04 2015 00:00:00  |
| November, 04 2015 00:00:00 | November, 04 2015 02:00:00  |
  --------------------------------------------------------

table `sites`:
  ----
| site |
| ---- |
| 1    |
| 2    |
| 3    |
| 4    |
  ---- 

table `all_data`:
  --------------------------------------
| data_date                  | data_site |
| ---------------------------|---------- |
| November, 02 2015 15:35:00 | 1         |
  --------------------------------------
```

and I want to get the following result:

```
  -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| data_date                  | data_site | start_day                  | end_day                    | site |
| ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
| null                       | null      | November, 01 2015 14:37:00 | November, 02 2015 00:00:00 | 1    |
| November, 02 2015 15:35:00 | 1         | November, 02 2015 00:00:00 | November, 03 2015 00:00:00 | 1    |
| null                       | null      | November, 03 2015 00:00:00 | November, 04 2015 00:00:00 | 1    |
| null                       | null      | November, 04 2015 00:00:00 | November, 04 2015 02:00:00 | 1    |
| null                       | null      | November, 01 2015 14:37:00 | November, 02 2015 00:00:00 | 2    |
| null                       | null      | November, 02 2015 00:00:00 | November, 03 2015 00:00:00 | 2    |
| null                       | null      | November, 03 2015 00:00:00 | November, 04 2015 00:00:00 | 2    |
| null                       | null      | November, 04 2015 00:00:00 | November, 04 2015 02:00:00 | 2    |
| null                       | null      | November, 01 2015 14:37:00 | November, 02 2015 00:00:00 | 3    |
| null                       | null      | November, 02 2015 00:00:00 | November, 03 2015 00:00:00 | 3    |
| null                       | null      | November, 03 2015 00:00:00 | November, 04 2015 00:00:00 | 3    |
| null                       | null      | November, 04 2015 00:00:00 | November, 04 2015 02:00:00 | 3    |
| null                       | null      | November, 01 2015 14:37:00 | November, 02 2015 00:00:00 | 4    |
| null                       | null      | November, 02 2015 00:00:00 | November, 03 2015 00:00:00 | 4    |
| null                       | null      | November, 03 2015 00:00:00 | November, 04 2015 00:00:00 | 4    |
| null                       | null      | November, 04 2015 00:00:00 | November, 04 2015 02:00:00 | 4    |
  -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

But instead I can only figure out how to get the following result ([see fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c97ad/1)):

```
  -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| data_date                  | data_site | start_day                  | end_day                    | site |
| ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
| null                       | null      | November, 01 2015 14:37:00 | November, 02 2015 00:00:00 | null |
| November, 02 2015 15:35:00 | 1         | November, 02 2015 00:00:00 | November, 03 2015 00:00:00 | 1    |
| null                       | null      | November, 03 2015 00:00:00 | November, 04 2015 00:00:00 | null |
| null                       | null      | November, 04 2015 00:00:00 | November, 04 2015 02:00:00 | null |
| null                       | null      | null                       | null                       | 2    |
| null                       | null      | null                       | null                       | 3    |
| null                       | null      | null                       | null                       | 4    |
  -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

using the following incorrect query:

```
select * from all_data d
full outer join date_ranges r on (r.start_day <= d.data_date and d.data_date < r.end_day)
full outer join sites s on s.site = d.data_site
```

Comment: `cross join` may hold the clue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A combination of `CROSS JOIN` and `LEFT JOIN` should do the trick for you.

Something like this..

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c97ad)

```
SELECT * 
FROM DATE_RANGES R
    CROSS JOIN SITES S 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ALL_DATA D ON (R.START_DAY <= D.DATA_DATE AND D.DATA_DATE < R.END_DAY)
                                        AND S.SITE = D.DATA_SITE
```

Comment: I would just use `between` in the join condition

Comment: does `between` include the lower but not the upper date in the range?